# Is there a way to fix the value of an object as constant in java?

Tags: java, final

We know that the `final` keyword creates a constant reference to an object. For example:

```
final Object object = new Object();
```

However, in this case , only the reference to the object is fixed and cannot be changed during the execution runtime of the program. I may still call setter methods on this object and alter the values of its data members. Is there a way I can prevent this in Java (equivalent of const in C++) ?

I understand a way where I should not define setters to this object class or should allow setting of values only once, but what if I want to pass this object as an argument to a function and do not want that function to alter values of this object's data members. I may still want to alter the values outside the function.

What should be the function prototype in that case?

Comment: Why can't you just set the fields to final? There is no way to guarantee that fields won't be changed, if you have setters on them.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra - If I set the fields to final, I can only set the value once but I don't want that. I just don't want the values to be changed in the purview of the function.

Comment: Just create a copy before passing it to function and pass the copy to function then it does not matter if the function changes it or not.

Comment: @AmitD - Thanks for the suggestion but is there something I could do at the function level? I mean every time creating a copy in the caller and then passing doesn't seem to be a good approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to define a read-only interface to the object, and put the setters only into the class, like this:

```
public interface ConstInterface {
    int getFirst();
    String getSecond();
}

public class MutableClass implements ConstInterface {
    private int _first;
    private String _second;
    int getFirst() {
        return _first;
    }
    void setFirst(int f) {
        _first = f;
    }
    String getSecond() {
        return _second;
    }
    void setSecond(String s) {
        _second = s;
    }
}

final ConstInterface obj = new MutableClass();
```

At this point, you can access `obj` as read-only through its interface. If you need to set properties, cast `obj` to `MutableClass`, and call the setters.

Comment: But again in this case, `setter` can't be called from anywhere.

Comment: @RohitJain Why not? You can do it after a cast, since you know the class behind the interface.

Comment: @RohitJain you can pass the interface as the parameter to the method (let's say `method1`) and have the concrete implementation in the method that calls this `method1`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Please help me understand this. This does not solve the problem of preventing the object to be modified within a function. It can be cast to MutableClass anywhere in the code even when it is passed to the function. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @AbhishekJain If you at all want to prevent method being invoked then either pass a copy or maintain list of final object references then if setter is invoked and reference is in that list then throw exception.

Comment: @AmitD - Still looking for a better way of doing this.

Comment: @AbhishekJain You can modify the object anywhere where you can access a `MutableClass`. If you make the class package-private, the code outside the package wouldn't be able to access the setters.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Hiding the class is the closest you can get to making the instance read-only from the point of view of the outside code. Unfortunately, you wouldn't be able to make it bullet-proof because of reflection: if there is a setter, reflection will be able to get to it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I understand that but my motive is to limit this to a function level security of the data.

Comment: @AbhishekJain Is the function inside or outside your class library? If it is inside, make `MutableClass` a static private class inside another class, so that functions outside the class wouldn't see `MutableClass`. If the function is outside your class library, give `MutableClass` default access by removing `public` to make the class invisible outside your library.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Looks like a healthy workaround but sad to know that there is no direct and simple way of doing it (similar to what const function parameters do in C++). I'll still let this question hang around for sometime to discover a possibly simpler way of doing it (before going ahead and accepting your answer). Hope you won't mind that. :)

Answer (score 3):

> but what if I want to pass this object as an argument to a function and do not want that function to alter values of this object's data members. I may still want to alter the values outside the function.

In that case, you should just pass a clone of the object instead of the object itself to the method.

Comment: @BheshGurung- Is there a way where I could do something at the function level?

Comment: @AbhishekJain: You have two options, either don't alter the state of the object inside the method or just have a statement that clones the object before you try to modify it in the method.

Comment: @AbhishekJain: The design-level solutions posted in other answers would the best if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You have several solutions.

1. First you can solve it by design. Create interface that does not have methods that can modify the object state. For example it will contain getters only. Now the variable type is interface. Client will not be able to modify the state.
2. If your class implements interface you can wrap it using dynamic proxy that prevents calling setters. BTW if you you class is actually collection or map you can use `Collections.unmodifireableMap()` or `Collections.unmodifireableList()` to make it indeed unmodifireable.
3. You can use byte code engineering. This will work even if your class does not implement any interface. There are 2 ways to do this. Libraries like javassist and cglib allow creating dynamic proxy that wrap concrete class. So, you can wrap your object using proxy created utilizing one of these libraries. The proxy will throw exception when setter is called.
4. Use byte code modification at compile time. For example AspectJ can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create a delegate which overrides all of the methods which will change the objects state and instead throw an exception or performs a no-op.